# Find the exact value of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{12}{5}\right)$

Tags: calculus

> Find the exact value of $\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{12}{5}\right)$.

The Taylor series expansion for $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is $$\tan^{-1}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}\dfrac{x^{2i+1}}{2i+1} = x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^5}{5}-\dfrac{x^7}{7}+\cdots.$$ Since $\dfrac{12}{5} > 1$, we can't use this formula. So how else should we try to find the exact value?

Comment: @Sophie I don't think so: $4 \arctan(1/5) = \arctan(120/119)$.

Comment: It is, however, $2 \arctan(2/3)$.

Comment: Does your Taylor series converge at $x = \frac {12}{5}$?

Answer (score 1):

You could also call it $\sin^{-1}(12/13)$ or $\cos^{-1}(5/13)$, but I doubt that there is anything more "exact" than that.  It's not, for example, a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Find a series for $\tan^{-1} x$ centered somewhere else (such as 1).

Or, find a series for $\tan^{-1} (x+1)$.

$\tan^{-1} \frac {12}{5} = \frac {\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1} \frac {5}{12}$

Comment: Can we find an exact value for $\tan^{-1} \dfrac{5}{12}$?

Comment: It is inside the radius of convergence.  So we can find an aproximate value, using the Taylor series.  I don't know what the exact value would be.  Clearly it is transcendental, but I don't think it is any ratio of $\pi$ so, $\tan^{-1} \frac {12}5$ is more "exact" than any other answer you might get.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Doug M. answered, since the argument is larger than $1$, it could be an idea to take into account the identity $$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\frac 1x)=\frac \pi 2$$ which, using Taylor, would give $$\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac \pi 2-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\,x^{2n+1}} $$ which would converge much faster.

Moreover, since it is an alternating series, you could in advance know the number of terms to be added if you want $k$ significant figures solving for $n$ $$\frac{1}{(2n+3)\,x^{2n+3}}\leq 10^{-k}\implies {(2n+3)\,x^{2n+3}}>10 ^k$$ Here again, appears Lambert function $$n > \frac{W\left(10^k \log (x)\right)}{2 \log (x)}-\frac{3}{2}$$ and since the argument $z$ in $W(z)$ is large, we can approximate $$W(z)=L_1-L2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\cdots\qquad(L_1=\log(z)\, , \, L_2=\log(L_1))$$ Fos $x=\frac{12}5$ and $k=100$ this would lead to $n=127$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the angle in right angled triangle with its opposite side  thirteen, adjacent side is five and hypotenuse thirteen, but there is no further exacter simplification.